# FabricJS Images Z-index after reload

Tags: javascript, css, fabricjs

I have implemented a canvas where I can add different objects. It all works fine until I reload the site and the images get added above the rest of the objects. I suppose it's because it takes longer for the image to load. I am trying to move each of the objects to the index they were inserted into using

```
this.canvas.add(object);
this.canvas.moveTo(object, parseInt(object.zindex));
```

Please note that I have attached the z-index as a property of the object, and I store it as soon as I add one object to canvas. 
For some reason, this is not changing anything on redraw and the objects continue to be where they were despite moving them to sorted index.
Has anyone encountered an issue like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
canvas.loadFromJSON(json, function() {
  canvas.renderAll();
}, function(o, object) {
  canvas.moveTo(object, object.index);
});
```

While [loading from json](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#loadFromJSON), use reviver and move the object to specified index.

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var index = 0,
  json;
var url = '//fabricjs.com/assets/pug.jpg';
fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function(img) {
  img.scaleToWidth(200)
  img.set({
    index: index++
  })
  canvas.add(img);
  canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({
    radius: 50,
    left:30,
    fill:'green',
    index: index++
  }));
})
canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 50,
  index: index++
}));

function saveCanvas() {
  json = canvas.toJSON(['index'])
}

function reloadCanvas() {
  canvas.loadFromJSON(json, function() {
    canvas.renderAll();
  }, function(o, object) {
    canvas.moveTo(object, object.index);
  })
}
```

```css
canvas{
 border:2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" name="button" onclick="reloadCanvas()">reload</button>
<button type="button" name="button" onclick="saveCanvas()">save</button><br>
<script type="text/javascript" src="
https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks! I think i fixed it by using canvas.insertAt instead of add(obj).